# How to store an image as BLOB and then display in Play!-powered website?

Tags: java, image, playframework, blob, yaml

I am trying to create an `initial-data.yml` file for a Play! Framework application. Part of the web application involves images (for profile picture and such) and I want to store them as BLOBs in my MySQL database (I know this isn't best practice, use of a file system will come later). I am wondering how I can put a "test" image in my YML file and how I can access it in the web app and display it. Any help would be appreciated. Below is what I have tried so far:

Part of YML:

```
Picture(Picture1):
     picture:     010001010100010101000101010001010100010101000101010001010100010101000101010001010100010101000101010001010100010101000101|image/png
```

Our Hibernate model has a picture as a `byte[]`.

Here is how I am trying to access the image in the HTML:

```
#{if _post.picture}
        <!-- display the picture -->
        <p> Hey, a picture should go here.</p>
        <img src="@{Application.showImage(_post.getPicture().getBinaryImage())}" alt="long islands for life"/>
    #{/if}
```

Here is `getBinaryImage()`

```
private ByteArrayInputStream getBinaryImage() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage));
            ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            return bais;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Right now I am getting a NullPointerException on the first line of this method because it seems that the image/byte[] is not being stored in the database. Any ideas how to get this appropriately stored in the database and then displaying on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your whole binary data in Base64 encoded form prepended by !!binary

```
binaryData: !!binary VGhpcyBTdHJpbmcgaXMgc3RvcmVkIGluIHlhbWwgZmlsZSB1c2luZyBiYXNlNjQ=
```

This example is from Play Framework samples

```
samples-and-tests/just-test-cases/test/yamlTestData.yml
```